# Limit number of likes / comments returns with graph facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit

I want to extract ALL likes and comments from my facebook fan page

I'm wondering if there's a limit for the number of return ? 
Because for the moment there is the pagination limit (25) and before going further, I want to be sure that I can extract all likes/comments on a specific post.

I've search a lot in the Graph API's doc but it's not clarify the situation...

Thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a higher limit:

```
/post-id/likes?limit=100
```

But you will never get ALL of them in one call, you have to use pagination to do that (for example, with a recursive function): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

Comment: Yes I want to do this, but I'm not sure if I can at the end get all item using a function ... Do you know that?

Comment: yes, that´s why i mentioned recursive functions. check those out, there are hundreds of tutorials about those for all important languages, it´s a very basic and old concept.

Comment: I just wanted to know if at the end I can retrieve all data concerning likes / comments on a Facebook page's posts. Seems to be sure, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: yes, with a recursive function you can get all of them ;)